# How to use javascript if statement correct?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this program that whenever the `expiration date` is exactly the same date as `today` the background of the `<div>` will change it color. But right now, the background color change only when my condition is `==` and when I try to use`>=` or `<=` the background color does not change. Also the background color change even the `expiration date` is not the same as the `date today`

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $today = date("m/d/Y");
var $expired = $passport_expiration;

function myDIV() {
  if ($today == $expired) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor="#ff4d4d";
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="myDiv">
    <div class="alert" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passport <?php echo "<strong><a href=\"view_latest_passport.php?id=$id\"> $passport</a> /&nbsp; Passport Expiration Date:</strong> $passport_expiration"; ?></div>
</div>
```

How I get the `$today` and `passport_expiration`, it is in my `query`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code looks like php and so do the syntax.

Comment: is that one of the reason why i get the wrong output?

Comment: `date("m/d/Y");` This is PHP function, in javascript we use `new Date() `object.

Comment: You are mixing php with javascript. Dates are object and javascript doesn't have object comparison so you have to do something like this. d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: thanks guys. so I must change `date("m/d/Y");` to `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="myDiv">
    <div class="alert" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Passport <?php echo "<strong><a href=\"view_latest_passport.php?id=$id\"> $passport</a> /&nbsp; 
    Passport Expiration Date:</strong> $passport_expiration"; ?></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="passport_expire_date" name="passport_expire_date" value="<?php echo $passport_expiration; ?>">
     <?php $date = date("m/d/Y "); ?>
     <input type="hidden" id="today_date" name="today_date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">
</div>
```

u need to assign that values in input field then only, it will be validated in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var today = document.getElementById("today_date");
var expired = document.getElementById("passport_expire_date");

function myDIV() {
  if ($today == $expired) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor="#ff4d4d";
  }
}
</script>
```